# javascript prompt asks user to enter a css property if incorrect the while loop is finished

Tags: javascript, css

create a while loop where a prompt pops up asks the user for color if the color is correct with the css property for example : `blue`, `red`, `#000000`

the prompt will keep asking the user and the background will change according to it but when the user dosent do it it will display a message

```
var choosecolor = prompt("what colour would you like");

while (choosecolor === document.body.style.backgroundColor){
    document.write("the color has been changed");
}
```

Comment: what is your question/problem?

Comment: This question is very unclear, especially this: `blue, red #000000` 65Wat?  Please read [ask]

Comment: Can't understand what you are saying is.

Comment: Looks like homework to me

Comment: the problem is that whatever is in the css property will change the background and it will keep looping however if it dosent prompt will finish. it

Comment: welcome to the world if infinite loops: the secret is that the condition must change in a while loop or else it logically goes on forever. If color is different, it does not terminate the loop, it just doesn't even enter in it. You should either change the background or the user input color inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd post it as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation.

It's not really your desired solution, but it's a kind of workaround:

```
var startChangingColor = setInterval(function() {changeColor()}, 1000);
function changeColor() {
   var chooseColor = prompt("What colour would you like?");
   document.body.style.backgroundColor = chooseColor;
   if (chooseColor === "") {
       clearInterval(startChangingColor);
  }
}
```

Try it out [here](https://jsfiddle.net/aw81azn9/).